# Function not being called in one scenario

Tags: powershell

I am getting a weird error in PowerShell. I have some code which is working in almost other 3 scenarios but not in one scenario, whatever be the case. Even if I try manually, it is not getting executed. The same code works fine in other scenarios, only variables differs.

Not working code:

```
#Removing snapshot - Keeping All Week Latest
$allweek = Get-Content "C:\RDS\Weekly_Preserved_Date.txt"
foreach ($aw in $allweek) {
  Select-String -Path "C:\RDS\latestdatetime.txt" -Pattern "$aw" |
    Measure-Latest |
    Select -ExpandProperty Line |
    Add-Content "C:\RDS\Weekly_Preserved_snaps.txt"
}
```

Working Code

```
$monthly = Get-Content "C:\RDS\six_months_latest.txt"
foreach ($monthsnaps in $monthly) {
  Select-String -Path "C:\RDS\latestdatetime.txt" -Pattern "$monthsnaps" |
    Measure-Latest |
    Select -ExpandProperty Line |
    Add-Content "C:\RDS\six_months_latest_snaps.txt"
}
```

[`Measure-Latest`](https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/measure-latest-finding-the-latest-date-time/) is a function. Can someone please help me on what could be the possible issue?

**EDIT**

Patterns would be something like 8/09/2015 or 5/30/2015

Weekly Preserved Date Contents:

```
8/09/2015  
8/03/2015
```

Six Months Latest Contents:

```
7/31/2015
6/30/2015
5/31/2015
```

Latest Date Time Contents:

```
8/24/2015 9:15:24 AM
8/17/2015 9:18:45 AM
7/31/2015 7:13:26 AM
7/23/2015 9:22:46 AM
8/03/2015 9:26:07 AM
7/27/2015 9:28:28 AM
8/09/2015 9:33:10 AM
7/30/2015 9:02:36 AM
8/21/2015 7:18:44 PM
5/31/2015 7:20:45 PM
6/30/2015 7:23:26 AM
```

Comment: You need to provide source for `Measure-Latest` in addition to input data. Describe the desired and actual outputs too.

Comment: Temporarily remove the rest of the pipeline to verify that the output of the `Select-String` statement is what you expect it to be.

Comment: @vonPryz I have see this in other post of his before. I added the link

Comment: @Matt: I've edited. But the same code is working in some other area on the same script and the pattern is same everywhere (as shown in edited part).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Done. Sample text file contents are provided.

Comment: Weekly Preserved Date Contents: has trailing spaces. Is that a copy error or are those present in the file.

Comment: Yes, it has trailing spaces. But how can I delete those? This file is created dynamically by some part of this script..

Comment: First we need to know if that is the issue. If you manually remove them does it work? Also since you are not using regex you could just use `-SimpleMatch`

Comment: Yes, when I remove that it is working. :) But how do we remove trailing spaces from each and every line of that file, when it is being created.?

Comment: Which file are you referring to? Weekly_Preserved_Date.txt? You don't explain how that file is created so we cannot answer that. NVM the solution is easy... Answer coming

Comment: @Matt: I am saying the file Weekly Preserved Date. Thank you very much Matt.. I got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that there are trailing spaces in one of your input files. That prevents a proper match since the file you are matching against does not have those spaces. From your Weekly_Preserved_Date.txt (I added some quotes to highlight the whitespace)

```
"8/09/2015  "
"8/03/2015  "
```

So a simple solution here would be to edit the pattern inside the `ForEach` loop.

```
Select-String -Path "C:\temp\latestdatetime.txt" -Pattern $aw.Trim()
```

The string method [`Trim()`](http://ss64.com/ps/trim.html) will remove leading and trailing whitespace.

This is of course assuming you cannot correct the cause of the spacing in the first place of you input file Weekly_Preserved_Date.txt.